# Django - How to get attribute from queryset objects list

Tags: python, django

I have a list of queryset objects like this: [<QuerySet [<Stuff: Phone>]>, <QuerySet [<Stuff: Vodka>]>, <QuerySet [<Stuff: Dictionary>]>]
Now i need to get attributes of each object from it.
Here is my html template

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Changes saved</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Изменены объекты:</p>
{% for el in elements %}
<p>{{el.name}} new price: {{el.price}}</p>
{% endfor %}
</body>
</html>
```

And in my browser i have just "new price:" 3 times

Comment: Can you add your view and model to the question?

Comment: You need to share more details about the query set. Can you share the model and view function information?

Comment: Are all objects inheriting from same class, i.e. `Product`? As above, share `models` and `views`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like from your sample, you are sending an array of querysets to the template, there are two ways you can get the data to show:

1. Get the first element from each queryset when looping

```py
{% for el in elements %}
    <p>{{el.first.name}} new price: {{el.first.price}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

2. Change the view to send in an array of objects not an array of querysets